# Mule logging with Log4j in Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, mule

I'm running Mule inside Apache Tomcat and using Log4j for logging. But I'm not able to make each application log to different files. 
I know it can be done when Mule is running in standalone mode. 
Is it possible to have a log file per-application in this scenario?

This is the log4j.xml config I use:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                     <param name="ConversionPattern"
                        value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:sss}] %5p %c{2}: %m%n" />
                </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
                <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </appender>

        <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
                <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/MYAPP.log"/>
                <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
                <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100"/>
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                     <param name="ConversionPattern"
                        value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:sss}] %5p %c{2}: %m%n"/>
                </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
                <priority value="INFO"/>
                <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
                <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>                
        </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The OOTB per-app logging feature is one of those functionalities that are only provided by mule standaone (as exlained [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Logging+With+Mule+ESB+3.x))

With that said you can leverage log4j configuration to achieve a similar result. To do that you have to add a custom log4.properties (or log4.xml) file to your webapp that uses a [FileAppender](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/FileAppender) and configure it according to your needs

Comment: I have a log4j.xml config file for every application deployed on Tomcat, but they all log to the same file. That file is not always the same, is one of the configured with 'FileAppender'. I'm not sure if it is a Mule or a Tomcat issue.

Comment: Could you share the appender configuration? Also do you have just one appender (the FileAppender) or multiple ose (e.g. you also have a console one)?

Comment: Just updated my question. I tried with FileAppender only but it didn't work either

Comment: I've just run some test using the mule-example-geomail with a log4j config similar to yours, but it worked just fine. It might be a classloading issue. Maybe some of the jars in your classpath contains a log4j.properties/xml that takes precedence over your, can you double check that?

Comment: It works fine if you have only one application running. The problem comes with more than one application.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have declared only one appender "FILE".

When you run multiple applications, you can declare additionnal appenders, to display informations based on package name. You will still have some informations in the main log file, those related to errors in org.mule... packages. I guess thats what you did.